# How to achieve different reactions at the first and second button click when there are many the same buttons? (Filter in js)

Tags: javascript, filter

there is a filter on the js, which consists of three identical buttons (named "green", "yellow", "red"), which are responsible for setting/removing the blur effect for the set of pictures located below.
When pressing the "green" button, a blur effect should be set for all pictures that have a value "green" of data-card property.
At the second click on the same button, the blur effect should be canceled for this category of pictures.
I solved this problem with a reception with a boolean flag:

```
let firstClick = true;

if (firstClick){
//..do at first click

firstClick = !firstClick;
}
else{
//..do at second click

firstClick = !firstClick;
}
```

However, the problem occurs when I click on the "green" button (this is the first click on the "green" button), and after that on another button, for example "red" (this is the first click on the "red" button). But the compiler perceives a click on the "red" button as a second click, although it is a different button.
The question is how to distinguish the behavior in different buttons?

In general, I solved the problem through a complete search and many if statements. Maybe there is an alternative way?

[Project demo in codepen](https://codepen.io/paunnil/pen/NWBGPpa)

```js
//main.js
function app() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.service__btn');
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.service__item');
  let firstClick = true;

  function setBlour(listOfCards) {
    listOfCards.forEach(item => {
      if (item.classList.contains(currentCategory)) {
        item.classList.add('blur');
      }
    });
  }

  function resetBlour(listOfCards) {
    listOfCards.forEach(item => {
      if (item.classList.contains(currentCategory)) {
        item.classList.remove('blur');
      }
    });
  }


  function highlightButton(butt) {
    if (!butt.classList.contains('service__btn__clicked')) {
      butt.classList.add('service__btn__clicked');
    }

    firstClick = !firstClick;
  }


  function unhighlight(butt) {
    if (butt.classList.contains('service__btn__clicked')) {
      butt.classList.remove('service__btn__clicked');
    }

    firstClick = !firstClick;
  }



  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      currentCategory = event.target.dataset.filter; //current category we get from clicked button
      let matchedCards = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-card="${button.dataset.filter}"]`);
      //is it first click? 
      if (firstClick) {
        if (!matchedCards[0].classList.contains('blur')) { // each click we have set of matchedCards, it's easy to check one of them (the first for example) if it have blur
          setBlour(matchedCards);
          highlightButton(button);
        } else { //it is a first clcik, but card have blur - so remove blur 
          resetBlour(matchedCards);
          unhighlight(button);
        }
      }
      //second click 
      else {
        if (!matchedCards[0].classList.contains('blur')) { //if there is no blur - add blur
          setBlour(matchedCards);
          highlightButton(button);
        } else { //second click and blur is present - so we need to remove it
          resetBlour(matchedCards);
          unhighlight(button);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
app()
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.service {
  background: #EDF2EC;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.service__top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.service__top-title {
  font-family: 'Inika', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  color: #499A18;
  max-width: 306px;
}

.service__filter-btn {
  margin-left: 142px;
}

.service__btn {
  border: 1px solid #E06733;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  font-family: 'Inika', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #E06733;
}

.service__btn__clicked {
  background: #E06733;
  border: 1px solid #E06733;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.service__btn+.service__btn {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.service__content {
  column-count: 3;
  gap: 0 116px;
}

.service__item {
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 330px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.service__item-title {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #E06733;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.service__item-text {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.service__item-description {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e1d5;
  display: none;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.animation {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="service">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="service__top">
        <h3 class="service__top-title">
          Caption and Description
        </h3>
        <div class="service__filter-btn">
          <button class="service__btn service__btn-type_green" data-filter="green"> Green</button>
          <button class="service__btn service__btn-type_yellow" data-filter="yellow">Yellow</button>
          <button class="service__btn service__btn-type_red" data-filter="red">Red</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service__content">
        <div class="service__item green" data-card="green">
          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Green color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__item red" data-card="red">
          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Red color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__item yellow" data-card="yellow">

          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Yellow color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__item red" data-card="red">
          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Red color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__item green" data-card="green">
          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Green color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__item red" data-card="red">
          <div class="service__item-description">
            <h4 class="service__item-title">Red color</h4>
            <p class="service__item-text">Description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet here. Please add relevant CSS to make a [mcve]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this